# I can't remove a formatting error- Python

Tags: python

For some background: I'm currently working on writing and transforming 30,000+ line data files. For some reason, a formatting error keeps happening in the middle of my current file:
`^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ 3.352388740E-05  1.956399032E+00  5.330716152E+09`

Where a normal line looks like these:

```
 3.352202475E-05  1.956847538E+00  5.329098588E+09
 3.351643682E-05  1.957293472E+00  5.327447942E+09
 3.351271152E-05  1.957742024E+00  5.325773881E+09
```

This becomes an issue in later analysis where I try to convert the split line to float, but it can't convert '^@' to float for obvious reasons.

In my script where I write the lines, I've tried various methods of getting rid of the ^@ string. My last attempt was:

```
def clean_file(new_file): 

    new_file_path = Path(new_file)
    lines = []
    with new_file_path.open('r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    with new_file_path.open('w') as file:
        for number, line in enumerate(lines):
            if number not in [7] and not line.startswith('^@'): 
                file.write(line)
```

Where 7 is used because line 7 is where the data starts after a few rows of headers. I've also used `line.replace('^@','')` and that hasn't worked either. I don't run into any problems writing the file, but the string of ^@ characters isn't removed no matter what I try.

What method would be best for fixing this error? Methods that remove the error or remove the line entirely are both fine.

Comment: What is `line.remove('^@','')`?  I can only find `str.replace()`

Comment: Also, what are you running between "having normal data" and "it's suddenly bad data"? Because that's where you want to solve problems, not after the fact.

Comment: Are you sure those are actual `^@` characters in the file? Some programs for displaying files display control characters with `^` prefixes, e.g. control-C is printed as `^C`. In this case, `^@` is character code `0`, which you can detect with `line.includes('\0')`

Comment: By opening the file for example with gedit, and searching for '3.352388740E-05  1.956399032E+00  5.330716152E+09', what do you have before? Is it not that you have strange characters around in your input file?

Comment: @Barmar That seems to be the issue, thank you.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm transforming the data in a txt file into formatting that can be used by my research engine. It's a simple script using file.write() method and this error only occurs on one line.

Comment: It's not a valid txt file if it contains those characters. Are you sure it's not a binary file?

Comment: To echo that: have a quick at your file in a hex editor to confirm whether you're already starting with bad data or not.

Comment: @Barmar From the amount of issues with the txt file, it may well be, but I was sent these from other physicists as txt files and asked to transform them. I'll probably mention to them that sending them to me in txt format is a bad idea...

Comment: if you just want to skip over the errors you can use `try` ... `except` blocks that only skip conversion errors, and be sure to limit it to said conversion errors so it will still throw a normal exception on other errors. [This doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) should be a good starting point...